# If a student is dismissed, is (or how is) that indicated on their transcript?

Tags: united-states, cheating, transcript-of-records, expulsion

As faculty, I've had to report academic misconduct (usually plagiarism) many times but that doesn't mean I know everything about how it works.  My understanding has always been that the only people who know about the report are the faculty who reported the incident, the student being reported and the conduct officer or honor committee (depending on the institution) investigating the report.  The student can certainly tell whoever they like but regardless of the outcome, everyone else is required to keep the information confidential.

But what happens if the result is dismissal (permanent separation from the university)?  Is there typically any indication of this on the student's transcript?  I've heard from colleagues that at some institutions, it will be indicated on the transcript but I'm not sure if that's correct.  If the dismissal is indicated and the misconduct was especially serious, e.g., rape, is that fact also reported?  What would it say?

Comment: I added the tag united-states to limit the scope, because otherwise it would be really too broad, and in many countries the example you give would lead to a criminal prosecution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transcripts usually do show that students have withdrawn or have been expelled for policy or academic infractions. The specific grounds, however, are probably not stated on most transcripts, perhaps for privacy reasons.

Comment: If another institution sees that sort of notation on the transcript and they request more information about the specifics, do they usually get it?

Comment: My instinct says no, they wouldn't. Colleges usually don't like to talk about the details of disciplinary actions.

Comment: Why is "expelled for plagiarism" more private than "failed Temporal Wormhole Dynamics II"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Because character flaws are more private than proficiency flaws.

Comment: I think this varies enormously by institution and maybe even by program. The only way to be sure what happens at your own school is to ask the registrar or office of academic affairs.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: The policy regarding transcripts should be uniform within a university, right?

Comment: @aeismail Not necessarily. They might be different for grad and undergrad, for example, and they might differ among grad programs and possibly certain undergrad programs too.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning: Different departments might have differing standards for releasing information about disciplinary proceedings. However, I would expect that what appears on the transcript is under the authority of the registrar (or equivalent), and should thus be uniform for undergraduates or graduates.